# Css - image on mobile is disrupted

Tags: html, css, media-queries, background-image

I'm creating my own portfolio website and I on mobile my background images behave strangely. When I'm discovering page sometimes background-image works perfectly and sometimes It looks really bad.

I have been asking once but this approach is not fixing my issue.

[Css - how to stop image scalling with size cover?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54463499/css-how-to-stop-image-scalling-with-size-cover)

Website: https://jozefrzadkosz-portfolio.pl

CSS Class on desktop:

```
.background-image {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url('~/header_train.jpg');
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    filter: brightness(30%) sepia(0.3);
    -webkit-filter: brightness(30%) sepia(0.3);
  }
```

and on mobile:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  header {
    .background-image {
      background-attachment: initial;
    }
  }
}
```

Pictures of background image shooted on mobile:

[image]

[image]

Comment: have you tried to add background-repeat: no-repeat;

Comment: I need to test this for a while but for now It solved the issue

Comment: Yeah it works, @godfather you can add this as an answer. Many thanks!

Comment: glad that this helped you ive added the answer ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the image is repeating itself so add this to your css: background-repeat: no-repeat;

Answer (score 1):

Just add `background-repeat: no-repeat;` into your class as below:

```css
.background-image {
    position: absolute;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url('~/header_train.jpg');
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    filter: brightness(30%) sepia(0.3);
    -webkit-filter: brightness(30%) sepia(0.3);
  }
```

I added it to your desktop class because this way it must apply also to the "mobile" view, however if you only face this issue on mobile, try to add it on the mobile class instead. (see below)

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  header {
    .background-image {
      background-attachment: initial;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
  }
}
```